# Multipart upload of streaming voice to S3

Tags: ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, streaming

I've managed to use webrtc to capture voice from the browser, MP3 encode client side, and stream over websocket to Ruby/Faye/Puma on heroku.  This is nice because there is no upload step after taking a long recording.

Now I want to stream to S3 as the recording is in progress.  You can't append to an S3 file but there are plenty of suggestions that you can send 5MB chunks, one-by-one, in a multipartupload.

I can't make sense of the docs or source for Aws-sdk-ruby V2.  It seems to want a whole file and to manage chunks under the hood.

Any clues?

Comment: Communicating directly with the REST API is not that hard to master.  You can manage the chunks any way that makes sense to you, if you take that approach.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if those docs are any better.  But I managed to figure it out using Pry and the docs to match stuff up.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out but seems a little wonky. The object hierarchy is all over the shop.  No doubt I'm doing it wrong.

```
@s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new()
@bucket = @s3.bucket(bucket_name)
@object = @bucket.object(file_name)
@upload = @s3.client.create_multipart_upload({bucket: bucket_name, key: @object.key})

part1 = {data: "my 1st 5MB chunk", part_number: 1}
part1[:output] = @s3.client.upload_part(body: part1[:data], bucket: bucket_name, key: @object.key, part_number: part1[:part_number], upload_id:@upload.upload_id)
part1[:etag] = part[:output][:etag]


part2 = {data: "my final chunk of any size", part_number: 2}
part2[:output] = @s3.client.upload_part(body: part2[:data], bucket: bucket_name, key: @object.key, part_number: part2[:part_number], upload_id:@upload.upload_id)
part2[:etag] = part[:output][:etag]

@object.multipart_upload(@upload.upload_id).complete(compute_parts: true)
```